# First countable geometric realization of a simplicial group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Suppose we have a simplicial group $G$.
What do we need from $G$ to get first countable $BG$, where $BG$ is a geometric realization of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

A CW-complex is first countable if and only if it's locally finite, and the geometric realization of a simplicial set is locally finite if and only if the original simplicial set was, in that only finitely many *non-degenerate* simplices may meet any other non-degenerate simplex. I don't see much improvement in this result from starting with a simplicial group.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I will think about that

Comment: Not so much improvement but a shortcut - for a group, it should suffice to check the condition only for simplices containing one fixed 0-simplex.